# Any Metro style datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Is there any good metro styled datepicker control that I can embed to website? jQuery UI, for example, doesn't look good with metro styled web page.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just looking for a jquery ui theme take a look at this [jquit theme](http://jquit.com/builder/#gcc=ffffff&gcb=d4d4d4&gct=525252&gci=d4d4d4&pcc=d4d4d4&acb=525252&o=ffffff&ghc=3399ff&ght=ffffff&ghi=ffffff&gdc=d4d4d4&gdb=d4d4d4&gdt=525252&tdc=3399ff&tdb=3399ff&tdt=ffffff&tdi=ffffff&ddc=d4d4d4&ddb=d4d4d4&ddt=525252&pxd=000000&asc=3399ff&ast=ffffff&goc=66B3FF&gob=66B3FF&got=ffffff&toc=66B3FF&tob=66B3FF&tot=ffffff&toi=ffffff&doc=66B3FF&dob=66B3FF&dot=ffffff&pxa=525252&gac=3399ff&gab=3399ff&gat=ffffff&tac=ffffff&tab=d4d4d4&tat=525252&tai=d4d4d4&dac=3399ff&dab=3399ff&dat=ffffff&dic=d4d4d4&dib=3399ff&dit=ffffff&gic=efdca9&gib=efdca9&git=525252&gii=525252&ec=c31d1d&eb=c31d1d&et=ffffff&ei=ffffff) [found here](http://www.jquery4u.com/bootstraps/metro-bootstraps/).
[image: metro datepicker]

Other alternatives are:

- MetroUI CSS offers a datepicker (and a complete user interface looking like metro)
  http://metroui.org.ua/calendar.php
- Also there is a theme for Bootstrap called BootMetro which also offers a datepicker.
  http://aozora.github.io/bootmetro/javascript.html#datepicker

If you're trying to get a fully metro styled page, I would recommend to use a theme in combination with bootstrap as it saves you a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

For metro style, visit Jquit (For jquery UI)

http://jquit.com/build-jquery-ui-themes-with-jquit-builder/

Comment: Note that this link offers something is much like the ThemeRoller of jquery UI, not a specific metro styled datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your datepicker using [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) of JQuery UI.

Also checkout this [**blog**](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-ui-datepicker/) for customizing. This [**DEMO**](http://media02.hongkiat.com/jquery-ui-datepicker/demo/datepicker/index.html) looks to be a good metro styled.